# Elastic Beanstalk fails to deploy my basic Node.js MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

ERROR

During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

I have know idea how to fix this? I can deploy my app on vercel in seconds but AWS is giving me pain for 3 days now. Please somebody help. I checked logs and it only returns this error

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the upgrade guide in the documentation?
https://metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-elastic-beanstalk.html#deploying-new-versions-of-metabase

You cannot use github.com/metabase/metabase/archive/v0.33.2.zip - that's the source code of the entire project - it's not the same as the binary version.

Comment: this doesn't work, uploading my source code does but not the codepipeline, it fails to npm install